# Como Carregar uma listview com mais de 30 colunas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, syntax-error

Estou tentando carregar uma `ListView` com mais de trinta colunas utilizando o seguinte código:

```
With ListV_P
Sheets("BANCO").Select

Dim UltimaLinha As Variant
Dim Linha As String

'.GetFirstVisible = True 'Abilita as linhas de Grades
'.View = lvwReport
'.FullRowSelect = True 'Seleciona a linha completa

.Gridlines = True
.View = lvwReport
.FullRowSelect = True

'Criar Cabeçalho
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="ID", Width:=40
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="NOME", Width:=100
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="ENDEREÇO", Width:=120
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="BAIRRO", Width:=60
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CIDADE", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="SEXO", Width:=40
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="IDADE", Width:=40
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CELULAR 1", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CELULAR 2", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="E-MAIL", Width:=85
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="ESTADO CIVIL", Width:=40
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="FORMAÇÃO ACADÊMICA", Width:=90
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CURSO 1", Width:=90
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CURSO 2", Width:=90
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CURSO 3", Width:=90
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="DEFICIÊNCIA", Width:=60
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="ÁREA DE INTERESSE 1", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="ÁREA DE INTERESSE 2", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="ÁREA DE INTERESSE 3", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="EXP. PROFISSIONAL 1", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CARGO 1", Width:=60
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="TEMPO", Width:=60
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="EXP. PROFISSIONAL 2", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CARGO 2", Width:=60
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="TEMPO 2", Width:=60
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="EXP. PROFISSIONAL 3", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="CARGO 3", Width:=60
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="TEMPO 3", Width:=60
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="PROGRAMA SOCIAL", Width:=70
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="INDICAÇÃO", Width:=40
.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="N° DO ENCAMINHAMENTO", Width:=40, Alignment:=2 'Alinhamento Centralizado
End With


ListV_P.ListItems.Clear 'Limpa os dados
UltimaLinha = Cells(Rows.Count, "1").End(xlUp).Row


'Lin = 7 'Comerça a exibir os dados apartir da linha 4 da tabela selecionada
For x = 7 To UltimaLinha

Set Lista = ListV_P.ListItems.Add(Text:=Cells(x, "A").Value)
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "B").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "C").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "E").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "F").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "F").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "I").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "N").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "P").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "Q").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "R").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "S").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "T").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "U").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "V").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "W").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "Y").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "Z").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AA").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AB").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AC").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AD").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AE").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AF").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AG").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AH").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AI").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AJ").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AK").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AL").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AM").Value
Lista.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Cells(x, "AN").Value
Next
```

Mas quando dou o comando para a execução do código o VBA me apresenta uma mensagem de erro:

> Erro em tempo de execução '1004': Erro de definição de aplicativo ou
>   de definição de objeto.

Por favor alguém me ajude ai. Sou Iniciante no VBA

Comment: Veja [este tutorial](https://excelmaniacos.com/2015/07/28/vba-popular-um-listview-preenchendo-dados-dentro-de-um-listview/) ou se for utilizar ListBox, utilizar `.RowSource` e veja [este tutorial](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/267-Maximum-columns-in-a-ListBox)

Answer (score -1):

### Dados de exemplo

Com o programa do [ExcelManiacos](https://excelmaniacos.com/2015/07/28/vba-popular-um-listview-preenchendo-dados-dentro-de-um-listview/), um teste foi realizado com dados da coluna A até AN, da linha 7 até 80. Como na tabela abaixo:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A7  | B7  | C7  | D7  | E7  | F7  | G7  | H7  | I7  | J7  | K7  | L7  | M7  | N7  | O7  | P7  | Q7  | R7  | S7  | T7  | U7  | V7  | W7  | X7  | Y7  | Z7  | AA7  | AB7  | AC7  | AD7  | AE7  | AF7  | AG7  | AH7  | AI7  | AJ7  | AK7  | AL7  | AM7  | AN7  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A8  | B8  | C8  | D8  | E8  | F8  | G8  | H8  | I8  | J8  | K8  | L8  | M8  | N8  | O8  | P8  | Q8  | R8  | S8  | T8  | U8  | V8  | W8  | X8  | Y8  | Z8  | AA8  | AB8  | AC8  | AD8  | AE8  | AF8  | AG8  | AH8  | AI8  | AJ8  | AK8  | AL8  | AM8  | AN8  |
| A9  | B9  | C9  | D9  | E9  | F9  | G9  | H9  | I9  | J9  | K9  | L9  | M9  | N9  | O9  | P9  | Q9  | R9  | S9  | T9  | U9  | V9  | W9  | X9  | Y9  | Z9  | AA9  | AB9  | AC9  | AD9  | AE9  | AF9  | AG9  | AH9  | AI9  | AJ9  | AK9  | AL9  | AM9  | AN9  |
| A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 | F10 | G10 | H10 | I10 | J10 | K10 | L10 | M10 | N10 | O10 | P10 | Q10 | R10 | S10 | T10 | U10 | V10 | W10 | X10 | Y10 | Z10 | AA10 | AB10 | AC10 | AD10 | AE10 | AF10 | AG10 | AH10 | AI10 | AJ10 | AK10 | AL10 | AM10 | AN10 |
| A11 | B11 | C11 | D11 | E11 | F11 | G11 | H11 | I11 | J11 | K11 | L11 | M11 | N11 | O11 | P11 | Q11 | R11 | S11 | T11 | U11 | V11 | W11 | X11 | Y11 | Z11 | AA11 | AB11 | AC11 | AD11 | AE11 | AF11 | AG11 | AH11 | AI11 | AJ11 | AK11 | AL11 | AM11 | AN11 |
| A12 | B12 | C12 | D12 | E12 | F12 | G12 | H12 | I12 | J12 | K12 | L12 | M12 | N12 | O12 | P12 | Q12 | R12 | S12 | T12 | U12 | V12 | W12 | X12 | Y12 | Z12 | AA12 | AB12 | AC12 | AD12 | AE12 | AF12 | AG12 | AH12 | AI12 | AJ12 | AK12 | AL12 | AM12 | AN12 |
| A13 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | I13 | J13 | K13 | L13 | M13 | N13 | O13 | P13 | Q13 | R13 | S13 | T13 | U13 | V13 | W13 | X13 | Y13 | Z13 | AA13 | AB13 | AC13 | AD13 | AE13 | AF13 | AG13 | AH13 | AI13 | AJ13 | AK13 | AL13 | AM13 | AN13 |
| A14 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | I14 | J14 | K14 | L14 | M14 | N14 | O14 | P14 | Q14 | R14 | S14 | T14 | U14 | V14 | W14 | X14 | Y14 | Z14 | AA14 | AB14 | AC14 | AD14 | AE14 | AF14 | AG14 | AH14 | AI14 | AJ14 | AK14 | AL14 | AM14 | AN14 |
| A15 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | I15 | J15 | K15 | L15 | M15 | N15 | O15 | P15 | Q15 | R15 | S15 | T15 | U15 | V15 | W15 | X15 | Y15 | Z15 | AA15 | AB15 | AC15 | AD15 | AE15 | AF15 | AG15 | AH15 | AI15 | AJ15 | AK15 | AL15 | AM15 | AN15 |
| A16 | B16 | C16 | D16 | E16 | F16 | G16 | H16 | I16 | J16 | K16 | L16 | M16 | N16 | O16 | P16 | Q16 | R16 | S16 | T16 | U16 | V16 | W16 | X16 | Y16 | Z16 | AA16 | AB16 | AC16 | AD16 | AE16 | AF16 | AG16 | AH16 | AI16 | AJ16 | AK16 | AL16 | AM16 | AN16 |
| A17 | B17 | C17 | D17 | E17 | F17 | G17 | H17 | I17 | J17 | K17 | L17 | M17 | N17 | O17 | P17 | Q17 | R17 | S17 | T17 | U17 | V17 | W17 | X17 | Y17 | Z17 | AA17 | AB17 | AC17 | AD17 | AE17 | AF17 | AG17 | AH17 | AI17 | AJ17 | AK17 | AL17 | AM17 | AN17 |
| A18 | B18 | C18 | D18 | E18 | F18 | G18 | H18 | I18 | J18 | K18 | L18 | M18 | N18 | O18 | P18 | Q18 | R18 | S18 | T18 | U18 | V18 | W18 | X18 | Y18 | Z18 | AA18 | AB18 | AC18 | AD18 | AE18 | AF18 | AG18 | AH18 | AI18 | AJ18 | AK18 | AL18 | AM18 | AN18 |
| A19 | B19 | C19 | D19 | E19 | F19 | G19 | H19 | I19 | J19 | K19 | L19 | M19 | N19 | O19 | P19 | Q19 | R19 | S19 | T19 | U19 | V19 | W19 | X19 | Y19 | Z19 | AA19 | AB19 | AC19 | AD19 | AE19 | AF19 | AG19 | AH19 | AI19 | AJ19 | AK19 | AL19 | AM19 | AN19 |
| A20 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | I20 | J20 | K20 | L20 | M20 | N20 | O20 | P20 | Q20 | R20 | S20 | T20 | U20 | V20 | W20 | X20 | Y20 | Z20 | AA20 | AB20 | AC20 | AD20 | AE20 | AF20 | AG20 | AH20 | AI20 | AJ20 | AK20 | AL20 | AM20 | AN20 |
| A21 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | I21 | J21 | K21 | L21 | M21 | N21 | O21 | P21 | Q21 | R21 | S21 | T21 | U21 | V21 | W21 | X21 | Y21 | Z21 | AA21 | AB21 | AC21 | AD21 | AE21 | AF21 | AG21 | AH21 | AI21 | AJ21 | AK21 | AL21 | AM21 | AN21 |
| A22 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | I22 | J22 | K22 | L22 | M22 | N22 | O22 | P22 | Q22 | R22 | S22 | T22 | U22 | V22 | W22 | X22 | Y22 | Z22 | AA22 | AB22 | AC22 | AD22 | AE22 | AF22 | AG22 | AH22 | AI22 | AJ22 | AK22 | AL22 | AM22 | AN22 |
| A23 | B23 | C23 | D23 | E23 | F23 | G23 | H23 | I23 | J23 | K23 | L23 | M23 | N23 | O23 | P23 | Q23 | R23 | S23 | T23 | U23 | V23 | W23 | X23 | Y23 | Z23 | AA23 | AB23 | AC23 | AD23 | AE23 | AF23 | AG23 | AH23 | AI23 | AJ23 | AK23 | AL23 | AM23 | AN23 |
| A24 | B24 | C24 | D24 | E24 | F24 | G24 | H24 | I24 | J24 | K24 | L24 | M24 | N24 | O24 | P24 | Q24 | R24 | S24 | T24 | U24 | V24 | W24 | X24 | Y24 | Z24 | AA24 | AB24 | AC24 | AD24 | AE24 | AF24 | AG24 | AH24 | AI24 | AJ24 | AK24 | AL24 | AM24 | AN24 |
| A25 | B25 | C25 | D25 | E25 | F25 | G25 | H25 | I25 | J25 | K25 | L25 | M25 | N25 | O25 | P25 | Q25 | R25 | S25 | T25 | U25 | V25 | W25 | X25 | Y25 | Z25 | AA25 | AB25 | AC25 | AD25 | AE25 | AF25 | AG25 | AH25 | AI25 | AJ25 | AK25 | AL25 | AM25 | AN25 |
| A26 | B26 | C26 | D26 | E26 | F26 | G26 | H26 | I26 | J26 | K26 | L26 | M26 | N26 | O26 | P26 | Q26 | R26 | S26 | T26 | U26 | V26 | W26 | X26 | Y26 | Z26 | AA26 | AB26 | AC26 | AD26 | AE26 | AF26 | AG26 | AH26 | AI26 | AJ26 | AK26 | AL26 | AM26 | AN26 |
| A27 | B27 | C27 | D27 | E27 | F27 | G27 | H27 | I27 | J27 | K27 | L27 | M27 | N27 | O27 | P27 | Q27 | R27 | S27 | T27 | U27 | V27 | W27 | X27 | Y27 | Z27 | AA27 | AB27 | AC27 | AD27 | AE27 | AF27 | AG27 | AH27 | AI27 | AJ27 | AK27 | AL27 | AM27 | AN27 |
| A28 | B28 | C28 | D28 | E28 | F28 | G28 | H28 | I28 | J28 | K28 | L28 | M28 | N28 | O28 | P28 | Q28 | R28 | S28 | T28 | U28 | V28 | W28 | X28 | Y28 | Z28 | AA28 | AB28 | AC28 | AD28 | AE28 | AF28 | AG28 | AH28 | AI28 | AJ28 | AK28 | AL28 | AM28 | AN28 |
| A29 | B29 | C29 | D29 | E29 | F29 | G29 | H29 | I29 | J29 | K29 | L29 | M29 | N29 | O29 | P29 | Q29 | R29 | S29 | T29 | U29 | V29 | W29 | X29 | Y29 | Z29 | AA29 | AB29 | AC29 | AD29 | AE29 | AF29 | AG29 | AH29 | AI29 | AJ29 | AK29 | AL29 | AM29 | AN29 |
| A30 | B30 | C30 | D30 | E30 | F30 | G30 | H30 | I30 | J30 | K30 | L30 | M30 | N30 | O30 | P30 | Q30 | R30 | S30 | T30 | U30 | V30 | W30 | X30 | Y30 | Z30 | AA30 | AB30 | AC30 | AD30 | AE30 | AF30 | AG30 | AH30 | AI30 | AJ30 | AK30 | AL30 | AM30 | AN30 |
| A31 | B31 | C31 | D31 | E31 | F31 | G31 | H31 | I31 | J31 | K31 | L31 | M31 | N31 | O31 | P31 | Q31 | R31 | S31 | T31 | U31 | V31 | W31 | X31 | Y31 | Z31 | AA31 | AB31 | AC31 | AD31 | AE31 | AF31 | AG31 | AH31 | AI31 | AJ31 | AK31 | AL31 | AM31 | AN31 |
| A32 | B32 | C32 | D32 | E32 | F32 | G32 | H32 | I32 | J32 | K32 | L32 | M32 | N32 | O32 | P32 | Q32 | R32 | S32 | T32 | U32 | V32 | W32 | X32 | Y32 | Z32 | AA32 | AB32 | AC32 | AD32 | AE32 | AF32 | AG32 | AH32 | AI32 | AJ32 | AK32 | AL32 | AM32 | AN32 |
| A33 | B33 | C33 | D33 | E33 | F33 | G33 | H33 | I33 | J33 | K33 | L33 | M33 | N33 | O33 | P33 | Q33 | R33 | S33 | T33 | U33 | V33 | W33 | X33 | Y33 | Z33 | AA33 | AB33 | AC33 | AD33 | AE33 | AF33 | AG33 | AH33 | AI33 | AJ33 | AK33 | AL33 | AM33 | AN33 |
| A34 | B34 | C34 | D34 | E34 | F34 | G34 | H34 | I34 | J34 | K34 | L34 | M34 | N34 | O34 | P34 | Q34 | R34 | S34 | T34 | U34 | V34 | W34 | X34 | Y34 | Z34 | AA34 | AB34 | AC34 | AD34 | AE34 | AF34 | AG34 | AH34 | AI34 | AJ34 | AK34 | AL34 | AM34 | AN34 |
| A35 | B35 | C35 | D35 | E35 | F35 | G35 | H35 | I35 | J35 | K35 | L35 | M35 | N35 | O35 | P35 | Q35 | R35 | S35 | T35 | U35 | V35 | W35 | X35 | Y35 | Z35 | AA35 | AB35 | AC35 | AD35 | AE35 | AF35 | AG35 | AH35 | AI35 | AJ35 | AK35 | AL35 | AM35 | AN35 |
| A36 | B36 | C36 | D36 | E36 | F36 | G36 | H36 | I36 | J36 | K36 | L36 | M36 | N36 | O36 | P36 | Q36 | R36 | S36 | T36 | U36 | V36 | W36 | X36 | Y36 | Z36 | AA36 | AB36 | AC36 | AD36 | AE36 | AF36 | AG36 | AH36 | AI36 | AJ36 | AK36 | AL36 | AM36 | AN36 |
| A37 | B37 | C37 | D37 | E37 | F37 | G37 | H37 | I37 | J37 | K37 | L37 | M37 | N37 | O37 | P37 | Q37 | R37 | S37 | T37 | U37 | V37 | W37 | X37 | Y37 | Z37 | AA37 | AB37 | AC37 | AD37 | AE37 | AF37 | AG37 | AH37 | AI37 | AJ37 | AK37 | AL37 | AM37 | AN37 |
| A38 | B38 | C38 | D38 | E38 | F38 | G38 | H38 | I38 | J38 | K38 | L38 | M38 | N38 | O38 | P38 | Q38 | R38 | S38 | T38 | U38 | V38 | W38 | X38 | Y38 | Z38 | AA38 | AB38 | AC38 | AD38 | AE38 | AF38 | AG38 | AH38 | AI38 | AJ38 | AK38 | AL38 | AM38 | AN38 |
| A39 | B39 | C39 | D39 | E39 | F39 | G39 | H39 | I39 | J39 | K39 | L39 | M39 | N39 | O39 | P39 | Q39 | R39 | S39 | T39 | U39 | V39 | W39 | X39 | Y39 | Z39 | AA39 | AB39 | AC39 | AD39 | AE39 | AF39 | AG39 | AH39 | AI39 | AJ39 | AK39 | AL39 | AM39 | AN39 |
| A40 | B40 | C40 | D40 | E40 | F40 | G40 | H40 | I40 | J40 | K40 | L40 | M40 | N40 | O40 | P40 | Q40 | R40 | S40 | T40 | U40 | V40 | W40 | X40 | Y40 | Z40 | AA40 | AB40 | AC40 | AD40 | AE40 | AF40 | AG40 | AH40 | AI40 | AJ40 | AK40 | AL40 | AM40 | AN40 |
| A41 | B41 | C41 | D41 | E41 | F41 | G41 | H41 | I41 | J41 | K41 | L41 | M41 | N41 | O41 | P41 | Q41 | R41 | S41 | T41 | U41 | V41 | W41 | X41 | Y41 | Z41 | AA41 | AB41 | AC41 | AD41 | AE41 | AF41 | AG41 | AH41 | AI41 | AJ41 | AK41 | AL41 | AM41 | AN41 |
| A42 | B42 | C42 | D42 | E42 | F42 | G42 | H42 | I42 | J42 | K42 | L42 | M42 | N42 | O42 | P42 | Q42 | R42 | S42 | T42 | U42 | V42 | W42 | X42 | Y42 | Z42 | AA42 | AB42 | AC42 | AD42 | AE42 | AF42 | AG42 | AH42 | AI42 | AJ42 | AK42 | AL42 | AM42 | AN42 |
| A43 | B43 | C43 | D43 | E43 | F43 | G43 | H43 | I43 | J43 | K43 | L43 | M43 | N43 | O43 | P43 | Q43 | R43 | S43 | T43 | U43 | V43 | W43 | X43 | Y43 | Z43 | AA43 | AB43 | AC43 | AD43 | AE43 | AF43 | AG43 | AH43 | AI43 | AJ43 | AK43 | AL43 | AM43 | AN43 |
| A44 | B44 | C44 | D44 | E44 | F44 | G44 | H44 | I44 | J44 | K44 | L44 | M44 | N44 | O44 | P44 | Q44 | R44 | S44 | T44 | U44 | V44 | W44 | X44 | Y44 | Z44 | AA44 | AB44 | AC44 | AD44 | AE44 | AF44 | AG44 | AH44 | AI44 | AJ44 | AK44 | AL44 | AM44 | AN44 |
| A45 | B45 | C45 | D45 | E45 | F45 | G45 | H45 | I45 | J45 | K45 | L45 | M45 | N45 | O45 | P45 | Q45 | R45 | S45 | T45 | U45 | V45 | W45 | X45 | Y45 | Z45 | AA45 | AB45 | AC45 | AD45 | AE45 | AF45 | AG45 | AH45 | AI45 | AJ45 | AK45 | AL45 | AM45 | AN45 |
| A46 | B46 | C46 | D46 | E46 | F46 | G46 | H46 | I46 | J46 | K46 | L46 | M46 | N46 | O46 | P46 | Q46 | R46 | S46 | T46 | U46 | V46 | W46 | X46 | Y46 | Z46 | AA46 | AB46 | AC46 | AD46 | AE46 | AF46 | AG46 | AH46 | AI46 | AJ46 | AK46 | AL46 | AM46 | AN46 |
| A47 | B47 | C47 | D47 | E47 | F47 | G47 | H47 | I47 | J47 | K47 | L47 | M47 | N47 | O47 | P47 | Q47 | R47 | S47 | T47 | U47 | V47 | W47 | X47 | Y47 | Z47 | AA47 | AB47 | AC47 | AD47 | AE47 | AF47 | AG47 | AH47 | AI47 | AJ47 | AK47 | AL47 | AM47 | AN47 |
| A48 | B48 | C48 | D48 | E48 | F48 | G48 | H48 | I48 | J48 | K48 | L48 | M48 | N48 | O48 | P48 | Q48 | R48 | S48 | T48 | U48 | V48 | W48 | X48 | Y48 | Z48 | AA48 | AB48 | AC48 | AD48 | AE48 | AF48 | AG48 | AH48 | AI48 | AJ48 | AK48 | AL48 | AM48 | AN48 |
| A49 | B49 | C49 | D49 | E49 | F49 | G49 | H49 | I49 | J49 | K49 | L49 | M49 | N49 | O49 | P49 | Q49 | R49 | S49 | T49 | U49 | V49 | W49 | X49 | Y49 | Z49 | AA49 | AB49 | AC49 | AD49 | AE49 | AF49 | AG49 | AH49 | AI49 | AJ49 | AK49 | AL49 | AM49 | AN49 |
| A50 | B50 | C50 | D50 | E50 | F50 | G50 | H50 | I50 | J50 | K50 | L50 | M50 | N50 | O50 | P50 | Q50 | R50 | S50 | T50 | U50 | V50 | W50 | X50 | Y50 | Z50 | AA50 | AB50 | AC50 | AD50 | AE50 | AF50 | AG50 | AH50 | AI50 | AJ50 | AK50 | AL50 | AM50 | AN50 |
| A51 | B51 | C51 | D51 | E51 | F51 | G51 | H51 | I51 | J51 | K51 | L51 | M51 | N51 | O51 | P51 | Q51 | R51 | S51 | T51 | U51 | V51 | W51 | X51 | Y51 | Z51 | AA51 | AB51 | AC51 | AD51 | AE51 | AF51 | AG51 | AH51 | AI51 | AJ51 | AK51 | AL51 | AM51 | AN51 |
| A52 | B52 | C52 | D52 | E52 | F52 | G52 | H52 | I52 | J52 | K52 | L52 | M52 | N52 | O52 | P52 | Q52 | R52 | S52 | T52 | U52 | V52 | W52 | X52 | Y52 | Z52 | AA52 | AB52 | AC52 | AD52 | AE52 | AF52 | AG52 | AH52 | AI52 | AJ52 | AK52 | AL52 | AM52 | AN52 |
| A53 | B53 | C53 | D53 | E53 | F53 | G53 | H53 | I53 | J53 | K53 | L53 | M53 | N53 | O53 | P53 | Q53 | R53 | S53 | T53 | U53 | V53 | W53 | X53 | Y53 | Z53 | AA53 | AB53 | AC53 | AD53 | AE53 | AF53 | AG53 | AH53 | AI53 | AJ53 | AK53 | AL53 | AM53 | AN53 |
| A54 | B54 | C54 | D54 | E54 | F54 | G54 | H54 | I54 | J54 | K54 | L54 | M54 | N54 | O54 | P54 | Q54 | R54 | S54 | T54 | U54 | V54 | W54 | X54 | Y54 | Z54 | AA54 | AB54 | AC54 | AD54 | AE54 | AF54 | AG54 | AH54 | AI54 | AJ54 | AK54 | AL54 | AM54 | AN54 |
| A55 | B55 | C55 | D55 | E55 | F55 | G55 | H55 | I55 | J55 | K55 | L55 | M55 | N55 | O55 | P55 | Q55 | R55 | S55 | T55 | U55 | V55 | W55 | X55 | Y55 | Z55 | AA55 | AB55 | AC55 | AD55 | AE55 | AF55 | AG55 | AH55 | AI55 | AJ55 | AK55 | AL55 | AM55 | AN55 |
| A56 | B56 | C56 | D56 | E56 | F56 | G56 | H56 | I56 | J56 | K56 | L56 | M56 | N56 | O56 | P56 | Q56 | R56 | S56 | T56 | U56 | V56 | W56 | X56 | Y56 | Z56 | AA56 | AB56 | AC56 | AD56 | AE56 | AF56 | AG56 | AH56 | AI56 | AJ56 | AK56 | AL56 | AM56 | AN56 |
| A57 | B57 | C57 | D57 | E57 | F57 | G57 | H57 | I57 | J57 | K57 | L57 | M57 | N57 | O57 | P57 | Q57 | R57 | S57 | T57 | U57 | V57 | W57 | X57 | Y57 | Z57 | AA57 | AB57 | AC57 | AD57 | AE57 | AF57 | AG57 | AH57 | AI57 | AJ57 | AK57 | AL57 | AM57 | AN57 |
| A58 | B58 | C58 | D58 | E58 | F58 | G58 | H58 | I58 | J58 | K58 | L58 | M58 | N58 | O58 | P58 | Q58 | R58 | S58 | T58 | U58 | V58 | W58 | X58 | Y58 | Z58 | AA58 | AB58 | AC58 | AD58 | AE58 | AF58 | AG58 | AH58 | AI58 | AJ58 | AK58 | AL58 | AM58 | AN58 |
| A59 | B59 | C59 | D59 | E59 | F59 | G59 | H59 | I59 | J59 | K59 | L59 | M59 | N59 | O59 | P59 | Q59 | R59 | S59 | T59 | U59 | V59 | W59 | X59 | Y59 | Z59 | AA59 | AB59 | AC59 | AD59 | AE59 | AF59 | AG59 | AH59 | AI59 | AJ59 | AK59 | AL59 | AM59 | AN59 |
| A60 | B60 | C60 | D60 | E60 | F60 | G60 | H60 | I60 | J60 | K60 | L60 | M60 | N60 | O60 | P60 | Q60 | R60 | S60 | T60 | U60 | V60 | W60 | X60 | Y60 | Z60 | AA60 | AB60 | AC60 | AD60 | AE60 | AF60 | AG60 | AH60 | AI60 | AJ60 | AK60 | AL60 | AM60 | AN60 |
| A61 | B61 | C61 | D61 | E61 | F61 | G61 | H61 | I61 | J61 | K61 | L61 | M61 | N61 | O61 | P61 | Q61 | R61 | S61 | T61 | U61 | V61 | W61 | X61 | Y61 | Z61 | AA61 | AB61 | AC61 | AD61 | AE61 | AF61 | AG61 | AH61 | AI61 | AJ61 | AK61 | AL61 | AM61 | AN61 |
| A62 | B62 | C62 | D62 | E62 | F62 | G62 | H62 | I62 | J62 | K62 | L62 | M62 | N62 | O62 | P62 | Q62 | R62 | S62 | T62 | U62 | V62 | W62 | X62 | Y62 | Z62 | AA62 | AB62 | AC62 | AD62 | AE62 | AF62 | AG62 | AH62 | AI62 | AJ62 | AK62 | AL62 | AM62 | AN62 |
| A63 | B63 | C63 | D63 | E63 | F63 | G63 | H63 | I63 | J63 | K63 | L63 | M63 | N63 | O63 | P63 | Q63 | R63 | S63 | T63 | U63 | V63 | W63 | X63 | Y63 | Z63 | AA63 | AB63 | AC63 | AD63 | AE63 | AF63 | AG63 | AH63 | AI63 | AJ63 | AK63 | AL63 | AM63 | AN63 |
| A64 | B64 | C64 | D64 | E64 | F64 | G64 | H64 | I64 | J64 | K64 | L64 | M64 | N64 | O64 | P64 | Q64 | R64 | S64 | T64 | U64 | V64 | W64 | X64 | Y64 | Z64 | AA64 | AB64 | AC64 | AD64 | AE64 | AF64 | AG64 | AH64 | AI64 | AJ64 | AK64 | AL64 | AM64 | AN64 |
| A65 | B65 | C65 | D65 | E65 | F65 | G65 | H65 | I65 | J65 | K65 | L65 | M65 | N65 | O65 | P65 | Q65 | R65 | S65 | T65 | U65 | V65 | W65 | X65 | Y65 | Z65 | AA65 | AB65 | AC65 | AD65 | AE65 | AF65 | AG65 | AH65 | AI65 | AJ65 | AK65 | AL65 | AM65 | AN65 |
| A66 | B66 | C66 | D66 | E66 | F66 | G66 | H66 | I66 | J66 | K66 | L66 | M66 | N66 | O66 | P66 | Q66 | R66 | S66 | T66 | U66 | V66 | W66 | X66 | Y66 | Z66 | AA66 | AB66 | AC66 | AD66 | AE66 | AF66 | AG66 | AH66 | AI66 | AJ66 | AK66 | AL66 | AM66 | AN66 |
| A67 | B67 | C67 | D67 | E67 | F67 | G67 | H67 | I67 | J67 | K67 | L67 | M67 | N67 | O67 | P67 | Q67 | R67 | S67 | T67 | U67 | V67 | W67 | X67 | Y67 | Z67 | AA67 | AB67 | AC67 | AD67 | AE67 | AF67 | AG67 | AH67 | AI67 | AJ67 | AK67 | AL67 | AM67 | AN67 |
| A68 | B68 | C68 | D68 | E68 | F68 | G68 | H68 | I68 | J68 | K68 | L68 | M68 | N68 | O68 | P68 | Q68 | R68 | S68 | T68 | U68 | V68 | W68 | X68 | Y68 | Z68 | AA68 | AB68 | AC68 | AD68 | AE68 | AF68 | AG68 | AH68 | AI68 | AJ68 | AK68 | AL68 | AM68 | AN68 |
| A69 | B69 | C69 | D69 | E69 | F69 | G69 | H69 | I69 | J69 | K69 | L69 | M69 | N69 | O69 | P69 | Q69 | R69 | S69 | T69 | U69 | V69 | W69 | X69 | Y69 | Z69 | AA69 | AB69 | AC69 | AD69 | AE69 | AF69 | AG69 | AH69 | AI69 | AJ69 | AK69 | AL69 | AM69 | AN69 |
| A70 | B70 | C70 | D70 | E70 | F70 | G70 | H70 | I70 | J70 | K70 | L70 | M70 | N70 | O70 | P70 | Q70 | R70 | S70 | T70 | U70 | V70 | W70 | X70 | Y70 | Z70 | AA70 | AB70 | AC70 | AD70 | AE70 | AF70 | AG70 | AH70 | AI70 | AJ70 | AK70 | AL70 | AM70 | AN70 |
| A71 | B71 | C71 | D71 | E71 | F71 | G71 | H71 | I71 | J71 | K71 | L71 | M71 | N71 | O71 | P71 | Q71 | R71 | S71 | T71 | U71 | V71 | W71 | X71 | Y71 | Z71 | AA71 | AB71 | AC71 | AD71 | AE71 | AF71 | AG71 | AH71 | AI71 | AJ71 | AK71 | AL71 | AM71 | AN71 |
| A72 | B72 | C72 | D72 | E72 | F72 | G72 | H72 | I72 | J72 | K72 | L72 | M72 | N72 | O72 | P72 | Q72 | R72 | S72 | T72 | U72 | V72 | W72 | X72 | Y72 | Z72 | AA72 | AB72 | AC72 | AD72 | AE72 | AF72 | AG72 | AH72 | AI72 | AJ72 | AK72 | AL72 | AM72 | AN72 |
| A73 | B73 | C73 | D73 | E73 | F73 | G73 | H73 | I73 | J73 | K73 | L73 | M73 | N73 | O73 | P73 | Q73 | R73 | S73 | T73 | U73 | V73 | W73 | X73 | Y73 | Z73 | AA73 | AB73 | AC73 | AD73 | AE73 | AF73 | AG73 | AH73 | AI73 | AJ73 | AK73 | AL73 | AM73 | AN73 |
| A74 | B74 | C74 | D74 | E74 | F74 | G74 | H74 | I74 | J74 | K74 | L74 | M74 | N74 | O74 | P74 | Q74 | R74 | S74 | T74 | U74 | V74 | W74 | X74 | Y74 | Z74 | AA74 | AB74 | AC74 | AD74 | AE74 | AF74 | AG74 | AH74 | AI74 | AJ74 | AK74 | AL74 | AM74 | AN74 |
| A75 | B75 | C75 | D75 | E75 | F75 | G75 | H75 | I75 | J75 | K75 | L75 | M75 | N75 | O75 | P75 | Q75 | R75 | S75 | T75 | U75 | V75 | W75 | X75 | Y75 | Z75 | AA75 | AB75 | AC75 | AD75 | AE75 | AF75 | AG75 | AH75 | AI75 | AJ75 | AK75 | AL75 | AM75 | AN75 |
| A76 | B76 | C76 | D76 | E76 | F76 | G76 | H76 | I76 | J76 | K76 | L76 | M76 | N76 | O76 | P76 | Q76 | R76 | S76 | T76 | U76 | V76 | W76 | X76 | Y76 | Z76 | AA76 | AB76 | AC76 | AD76 | AE76 | AF76 | AG76 | AH76 | AI76 | AJ76 | AK76 | AL76 | AM76 | AN76 |
| A77 | B77 | C77 | D77 | E77 | F77 | G77 | H77 | I77 | J77 | K77 | L77 | M77 | N77 | O77 | P77 | Q77 | R77 | S77 | T77 | U77 | V77 | W77 | X77 | Y77 | Z77 | AA77 | AB77 | AC77 | AD77 | AE77 | AF77 | AG77 | AH77 | AI77 | AJ77 | AK77 | AL77 | AM77 | AN77 |
| A78 | B78 | C78 | D78 | E78 | F78 | G78 | H78 | I78 | J78 | K78 | L78 | M78 | N78 | O78 | P78 | Q78 | R78 | S78 | T78 | U78 | V78 | W78 | X78 | Y78 | Z78 | AA78 | AB78 | AC78 | AD78 | AE78 | AF78 | AG78 | AH78 | AI78 | AJ78 | AK78 | AL78 | AM78 | AN78 |
| A79 | B79 | C79 | D79 | E79 | F79 | G79 | H79 | I79 | J79 | K79 | L79 | M79 | N79 | O79 | P79 | Q79 | R79 | S79 | T79 | U79 | V79 | W79 | X79 | Y79 | Z79 | AA79 | AB79 | AC79 | AD79 | AE79 | AF79 | AG79 | AH79 | AI79 | AJ79 | AK79 | AL79 | AM79 | AN79 |
| A80 | B80 | C80 | D80 | E80 | F80 | G80 | H80 | I80 | J80 | K80 | L80 | M80 | N80 | O80 | P80 | Q80 | R80 | S80 | T80 | U80 | V80 | W80 | X80 | Y80 | Z80 | AA80 | AB80 | AC80 | AD80 | AE80 | AF80 | AG80 | AH80 | AI80 | AJ80 | AK80 | AL80 | AM80 | AN80 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

#### Código

```
Private Sub PopularListView()

    'Declaração de variáveis
    Dim wksOrigem As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim LstItem As ListItem
    Dim linCont As Long
    Dim colCont As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    'Definição da planilha de origem
    Set wksOrigem = Worksheets("BANCO")

    'Definição do range de origem
    Set rData = wksOrigem.Range("A7").CurrentRegion

    'Adicionar cabeçalho no listview com laço de repetição 'For'
    For Each rCell In rData.Rows(1).Cells
        Me.ListV_P.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rCell.Value, Width:=90
    Next rCell

    'Alimentar variável linCont com número de linhas do intervalo fonte
    linCont = rData.Rows.Count

    'Alimentar variável colCont com número de linhas do intervalo fonte
    colCont = rData.Columns.Count

    'Popular o ListView
    For i = 2 To linCont
        Set LstItem = Me.ListV_P.ListItems.Add(Text:=rData(i, 1).Value)
        For j = 2 To colCont
            LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rData(i, j).Value
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Ajustes de algumas propriedades importantes do ListView
    With Me.ListV_P
        .Gridlines = True                        'linhas de grade visíveis (true)
        .HideColumnHeaders = False               'False para cabeçalho visível e True para invisível
        .View = lvwReport                        'Ajustar visualização do listview
    End With
    'se quiser detalhes da propriedade .view consulte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733652(v=vs.60).aspx)

    'Chamar o procedimento para popular o Listview1
    Call PopularListView

End Sub
```

### Resultado

[image: Resultado]