# Formatação correta para hora excel vba

Tags: vba, excel-vba, microsoft-excel, userform

Boa tarde!

Eu estou encontrando um problema que eu imaginei que fosse básico mas que não consegui resolver.

Eu tenho um `Userform (Entradas)` para cadastrar entradas. Essas entradas são jogadas para a minha planilha no Excel. No meu segundo `Userform (Listagem)` eu puxo os dados dessa planilha numa `Listview`. Até agora tenho conseguido puxar esses dados - já inseridos e armazenados na minha planilha -, menos um: a hora.

A ideia é quando eu fizer um cadastro (pelo `Userform` de entradas), eu puxo a data e a hora automaticamente sem o usuário ver. Na planilha esses dados aparecem normalmente, apenas quando eu puxo esses dados na minha `Listview` é que a minha hora aparece em formato errado.

Na planilha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na Listview:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu achei que declarar a minha `TextBox` de hora como `Time` seria o suficiente, já que com a data parece ter funcionado.

Segue meu código no primeiro `Userform (Entradas)`:

```
Private Sub BtnSalvar_Click()

Dim LINHA As Integer

LINHA = Planilha3.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1


Planilha3.Range("A" & LINHA) = TextData.Text
Planilha3.Range("B" & LINHA) = TextHora.Text

Private Sub TextHora_AfterUpdate()

    TextHora.Value = Format(TextHora, "00"":""00"":""00")

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    TextData = Date
    TextHora = Time

End Sub
```

Eu não coloquei o código todo, pois ficaria muito extenso, então deixei apenas os trechos que tinham minima ligação com as variáveis do meu problema.

Alguém sabe me dizer como resolver isso? Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Somente Texto**

Não é necessário formatar se você deseja importar somente o texto para a ListView, pois ele já está formatado corretamente na planilha.

Foi realizado um teste com os seguintes dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o código [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300799/como-carregar-uma-listview-com-mais-de-30-colunas):

```
Private Sub PopularListView()

    'Declaração de variáveis
    Dim wksOrigem As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim LstItem As ListItem
    Dim linCont As Long
    Dim colCont As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    'Definição da planilha de origem
    Set wksOrigem = Worksheets("Planilha1")

    'Definição do range de origem
    Set rData = wksOrigem.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

    'Adicionar cabeçalho no listview com laço de repetição 'For'
    For Each rCell In rData.Rows(1).Cells
        Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rCell.Value, Width:=90
    Next rCell

    'Alimentar variável linCont com número de linhas do intervalo fonte
    linCont = rData.Rows.Count

    'Alimentar variável colCont com número de linhas do intervalo fonte
    colCont = rData.Columns.Count

    'Popular o ListView
    For i = 2 To linCont
        Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rData(i, 1).Text)
        For j = 2 To colCont
            LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rData(i, j).Text
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Ajustes de algumas propriedades importantes do ListView
    With Me.ListView1
        .Gridlines = True                        'linhas de grade visíveis (true)
        .HideColumnHeaders = False               'False para cabeçalho visível e True para invisível
        .View = lvwReport                        'Ajustar visualização do listview
    End With
    'se quiser detalhes da propriedade .view consulte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733652(v=vs.60).aspx)

    'Chamar o procedimento para popular o Listview1
    Call PopularListView

End Sub
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Valor da hora e formatar**

Já se deseja guardar o valor da hora como uma variável para realizar cálculos, declare uma variável hora e atribua o valor da célula (`hora = rData(i, 2).Value`).

Depois formate para o formato desejado ao inserir na ListView:`LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Format(hora, "hh:mm:ss")`

```
Private Sub PopularListView()

    'Declaração de variáveis
    Dim wksOrigem As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim LstItem As ListItem
    Dim linCont As Long
    Dim colCont As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim hora As Double

    'Definição da planilha de origem
    Set wksOrigem = Worksheets("Planilha1")

    'Definição do range de origem
    Set rData = wksOrigem.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

    'Adicionar cabeçalho no listview com laço de repetição 'For'
    For Each rCell In rData.Rows(1).Cells
        Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rCell.Value, Width:=90
    Next rCell

    'Alimentar variável linCont com número de linhas do intervalo fonte
    linCont = rData.Rows.Count

    'Alimentar variável colCont com número de linhas do intervalo fonte
    colCont = rData.Columns.Count

    'Popular o ListView
    For i = 2 To linCont
        hora = rData(i, 2).Value
        Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rData(i, 1).Text)
        LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Format(hora, "hh:mm:ss")
    Next i

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Ajustes de algumas propriedades importantes do ListView
    With Me.ListView1
        .Gridlines = True                        'linhas de grade visíveis (true)
        .HideColumnHeaders = False               'False para cabeçalho visível e True para invisível
        .View = lvwReport                        'Ajustar visualização do listview
    End With
    'se quiser detalhes da propriedade .view consulte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733652(v=vs.60).aspx)

    'Chamar o procedimento para popular o Listview1
    Call PopularListView

End Sub
```

Comment: Opa Daniel! Cara muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Eu na verdade já estou conseguindo puxar os dados pra listview, o problema é que eu não to sabendo tratar a hora. O negócio é que na hora de puxar os dados da planilha pra listview o meu código está diferente do seu, e eu não sei como fazer funcionar com a sua solução, não ta dando certo. Será que você poderia dar uma olhada no meu [código](https://jsfiddle.net/kai98/efxn81jy/) pra poder me ajudar?

Comment: Veja a parte da resposta que possui formatação `LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Format(hora, "hh:mm:ss")`, em que é utilizado o Format(). Ou poderia ser da seguinte forma também `LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Format(rData(i, 2).Value, "hh:mm:ss")`. No seu código você deve formatar a célula com os dados, então poderia mudar de `Planilha3.Range("b" & i)` para `Planilha3.Range("b" & i).Text`. Ou formatar com `Format(Planilha3.Range("b" & i), "hh:mm:ss")`. Em que a coluna B é um exemplo, mas deve ser alterada para a coluna com os dados de hora.

Comment: Hahaha, cara deu certo. Muito obrigado mesmo. Eu sou um completo noob com Visual, nem imaginei que daria pra fazer isso. A única coisa que eu precisei fazer foi colocar um ```Planilha3.Range("b" & i).Text```. Obrigado pela paciência, tudo de bom!